# Merge Two Excel Sheet to one Excel Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have two excel sheets in C:\ADISE\Export.
 1st having data as

```
rollno name mark1 mark2 mark3
```

and 2nd excel sheet as

```
rollno name mark4 mark5 mark6 mark7 mark8
```

I need to merge these to one excel sheet as

```
rollno name mark1 mark2 mark3 mark4 mark5 mark6 mark7 mark8
```

Comment: What issues are you facing in merging? What have you tried ?

Comment: `vlookup()` can be used for this.

Answer (score 0):

in your second sheet you can put several formula at the top to do VLOOKUP using ROLLNO to get mark4 mark5 mark6 mark7 mark8

something like:

```
=VLOOKUP(A:A,Sheet2!A:G,3)
```

HTH

Philip

Comment: or you can use formulae to copy and merge all the data from both sheets onto the 3rd summary sheet!